# How to solve this problem (geometry)?

Tags: geometry

In the acute-angled triangle $ABC$, point $D$ is located on $BC$ so that $\;BD:CD = 2:3\;$ and point $E$ is located on $AC$ so that $\;AE:EC = 3:4\;$.

Point $F$ is where $AD$ and $BE$ cross. Find $\;\;\cfrac{AF}{FD}\cdot\cfrac{BF}{FE}\;$.

[image]

Comment: Also please add what you have tried to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $(XYZ)$ denote the area of $\triangle XYZ$. Then we have: $\dfrac{(BAF)}{(BDF)}= \dfrac{AF}{FD}= \dfrac{(AEF)}{(DEF)}= \dfrac{(BAF)+(EAF)}{(BDF)+(EDF)}= \dfrac{(BAE)}{(BDE)}= \dfrac{\dfrac{3}{4}(BAC)}{\dfrac{2}{3}(BEC)}= \dfrac{9}{8}\cdot \dfrac{4}{1} = \dfrac{9}{2}$. Can you do the other half?

Comment: $\cfrac{(FAB)}{(EAF)}$ = $\cfrac{BF}{FE}$ = $\cfrac{(DEF)}{(DFB)}$ = $\cfrac{(BAD)}{(ADE)}$ = $\cfrac{\cfrac{2}{3}(BAC)}{\cfrac{3}{4}(ADC)}$ = $\cfrac{8}{9}*\cfrac{5}{3}$ = $\cfrac{40}{27}$, so the answer should be $\cfrac{20}{3}$ if I haven't made a mistake, Thank you very much :)

Comment: Make sure you add the numerators and denominators as done above.

Comment: @DeepSea What is the theorem involved in this solution? From what I see, it works kinda like this: If a line is drawn from a vertex of a triangle to some point on its opposite side, dividing this side in some ratio x:y, then the areas of the triangles cut from the original triangle are in the same ratio as the pieces cut from the base. But I see such thing for the first time. Does this theorem has a name, so that I could look up more about it? Is there any geometry textbook where it's been mentioned?